# Where can I ask about CNC machines?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have question about programming CNC machines. Should I ask on Electrical Engineering or Robotics or where exactly?

Is there any place dedicated for asking about CNC machines or something like this?

According to Wikipedia:

> A CNC router (Or Computer Numerical Control router) is a computer-controlled cutting machine related to the hand held router used for cutting various hard materials, such as wood, composites, aluminium, steel, plastics, and foams.

Comment: Is it a programming question or a question about the CNC machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Robotics [seems a good fit](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> We ask and answer questions about robotics and automation systems, control systems, control theory, algorithms, actuators and sensors.
>
> the writing algorithms [of] for robotic systems

But also Stack Overflow can be the site to go if the question is strictly programming related.

Be aware that questions that are too general or broad won't do good anywhere, so if you ask a question, be specific.

Answer (score 14):

Engineering seems to be getting quite a few CNC questions:  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc

And there probably are still good questions and answers there.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any place dedicated for asking about CNC machines or something like this?

Not any specific StackExchange forum as far as I know. There are plenty of other forums though:

1. Reddit subs:

   - [CNC](https://www.reddit.com/r/CNC/)
   - [Machining](https://www.reddit.com/r/machining/)
   - [hobbycnc](https://www.reddit.com/r/hobbycnc/)
   - [Machinists](https://www.reddit.com/r/Machinists/)
   - There are plenty of other relevant subreddits, just search it there.
2. [practicalmachinist](http://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/) is also a great forum. A lot of pro people there.
3. [CNCZone](http://www.cnczone.com/forums/)
4. [cnc-professional-forum](http://cnc-professional-forum.com/)
5. [planet-cnc](http://forum.planet-cnc.com/)
6. Some of the relevant StackOverflow / StackExchange tags-forums:

   - [3D printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/)
   - Robotics [CNC](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc?sort=newest&pageSize=15) tag
   - Engineering [CNC](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cnc?sort=newest&pageSize=15) tag
   - StackOveflow tags: [g-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g-code?sort=newest&pageSize=50), [CNC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cnc?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

I'm sure there are tens, if not hundreds, more. Feel free to edit my post and add other active professional groups you know.

Answer (score 4):

There was a Digital Fabrication stackexchange beta, which was derailed by being renamed to "maker' or some such:

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/digital-fabrication

and then was re-launched under the original name.

Comment: It didn't survive - page now says "The Digital Fabrication site didn't have enough activity during the beta, and has been closed."

Answer (score 0):

Also [woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com) is an option if it's more woodworking related question(s) (like [Maslow CNC](https://www.maslowcnc.com/) machine).